# Keep pop up hover content open while hovering over content/body

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to create a custom hover using javascript and css.

Everything works great, I am able to toggle the class to show and hide the popup/hover bubble. 
(popup-body)

However, I would like the bubble to also stay open while the cursor is hovering over the bubble.
(popup-body)

This closes immediately after leaving the popup-link, which makes the hover action useless if I render any links inside the popup-body. Please help!

HTML/ERB

```
<div class="popup-container">
  <span class="popup-link">Partner disclosure</span>
  <span class="popup-body popup-bottom">
    <h3>Partner relationships</h3>

    <p>stuffs in popup body</p>
  </span>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).on('mouseleave click', '.popup-body', function() {
   $(".popup-body").removeClass('show-popup');
})

### if mobile device
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {

  $(document).on('click', '.popup-link', function() {
     var popupContent = $(this).parent('.popup-container').find('.popup-body');
     if (!popupContent.hasClass('show-popup')) {
       popupContent.addClass('show-popup');
     } else {
       popupContent.removeClass('show-popup');
     }
  })

  $(document).on('touchstart', '.page-content', function(e) {
    if ( !e.target.classList.contains(".popup-body") ) {
      $(".popup-body").removeClass('show-popup');
    }
  });

} else { ###desktop

  $(document).on('mouseenter', '.popup-link', function() {
      var popupContent = $(this).parent('.popup-container').find('.popup-body');
      popupContent.addClass('show-popup');
  })

  $(document).on('click', '.page-content', function(e) {
    if ( !e.target.classList.contains(".popup-body") ) {
      $(".popup-body").removeClass('show-popup');
    }
  });
}
```

CSS

```
.popup-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup-container .popup-body {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 676px;
  background-color: $color-white;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.popup-container .show-popup {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  @include susy-breakpoint(0 $breakpoint-tablet-landscape, 8) {
    width: 350px;
  }
}

.popup-bottom {
  top: 135%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.popup-bottom::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 5%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 0 10px 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff transparent;
}

.popup-link {
  color: $color-brand-1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.popup-link:hover {
  color: $color-link-hover;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding you, but if you just want the body to go away when it's position is left, why not add the mouseexit function to *that* element instead? Here is what I'm referring to, in a snippet.

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter click', '.popup-link', function() {
   var popupContent = $(this).parent('.popup-container').find('.popup-body');
   popupContent.addClass('show-popup');
})

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.popup-body', function() {
   $(".popup-body").removeClass('show-popup');
})

$(document).on('click touch', function(e) {
  if ( !e.target.classList.contains(".popup-body") ) {
    $(".popup-body").removeClass('show-popup');
  }
});
```

```css
.popup-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup-container .popup-body {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 676px;
  background-color: $color-white;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.popup-container .show-popup {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  @include susy-breakpoint(0 $breakpoint-tablet-landscape, 8) {
    width: 350px;
  }
}

.popup-bottom {
  top: 135%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup-container">
  <span class="popup-link">Partner disclosure</span>
  <span class="popup-body popup-bottom">
    <h3>Partner relationships</h3>

    <p>stuffs in popup body</p>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: wow this is perfect. is there anyway in which the mouseleave can work for both the popup-body and popup-link?

Comment: It depends on what you mean. Technically you'd fire a mouseexit event crossing over into the body. You could always set a timeout. What is the intended use-case? I originally thought it was the body stayed *until* the mouse *left* the body. Did you want it to leave under other circumstances as well?

Comment: This works actually! just wish i knew how to make it detect mobile.

so that i can make it a click on and click off action instead.

Comment: You can attach click events as well.

Comment: I attached a click on the link element now as well. You can also sense if a click is on the body and remove the class like that as well.

Comment: Oh wow, i didnt not know you can do that. Out of curiosity, would it be possible to do an onclick outside the popup? To give the flexibility of closing the pop up a lot easier.

Comment: You would have to attach a click listener to the body. That's where things get a little trickier. I'll do some research (it's been forever) and I'll get back to you. :)

Comment: Take a look at my code and see if it works for you. I'm not sure if this is the *best* practice for handling this per see, but it definitely seems to work the way you are intending. I'd probably make the code more D.R.Y. (Don't Repeat Yourself). You can cache the variables instead of parsing the DOM to find them every time. `var popupBody = $('.popup-body);` etc

Comment: This works great on desktop. not so much on mobile. Still a solid answer thanks!

Comment: Let me see if there's a way to test it. I was almost positive that clicks translated to touch events on browsers. I'll see what I can do. :)

Comment: There seems to be a 'touchstart' jQuery event. I added it to the click event. Let me know how that works for you. :)

Comment: this helped a lot. i got something more or less working. but its messy. "mouseenter" gets triggered in mobile which is the thing that makes it hard to work. 

however i've updated my question with the edits i am using